# Android GridView issue with position 0

Tags: android, image, gridview

I'm working with the GridView example at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html). I'm adapting the example code to display a Sudoku board using the GridView, 9x9 images. (It could be 9x9 text digits, but I've chosen images).

The example code contains this for setting the ImageViews (mThumbIds is an array of image resource ids):

```
    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

All good so far and it initialises fine.

I keep track of the imageViews for each cell so I can use them when I want to display a different image (by clicking on the image itself).

Again this works fine, *except for position 0* (the first item in the GridView). This resolutely stays with the image set above from mThumbIds.
i.e.
I use

```
    imageView.setImageResource(imgId)
```

to change images in different locations around the grid and they all change except for position 0.

The code runs with no exceptions, but the image never changes.
Is there something special about position 0? This is becoming a hair-loss scenario - any advice gratefully received.

Comment: GridLayout would be a better choice for a sudoku game by the way http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Your getView code seems fine, but it's probably not being called. You need to trigger a redraw.

If your adapter is a BaseAdapter (or a subclass of BaseAdapter), call notifyDataSetChanged() on the grid's adapter to force the redraw.
Something like:

((BaseAdapter)mGridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();